# Centroid of spherical shell

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem says: We have a spherical shell centered at the origin with radius = 30, find the centroid of the part of the sphere in the first octant.

I figured y_bar=x_bar=z_bar because of symmetry, so i only had to find one of them.

$$z= \sqrt{30^2-x^2-y^2}$$

switched to polar coordinates and got $z=\sqrt{30^2-r^2}$

then i had the double integral from $0$ to $\pi/2 d\theta$ and from $0$ to $30 rdr$

i divided this by the area of the circle in the plane, and ended up getting $20$, but the answer should be $15$.

Is there something wrong with the logic here, or did i screw up the math?

Comment: Hi, I added latex formatting but I am not sure about some sentences you formulated. For example when you describe the limits of the integral you usually don't have $dr$ or $d\theta$... Could you please check what you really mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're using $r$ as if you were integrating an area in the plane. But in this case $r$ is a function of $z$.  To avoid this confusion, I would use some symbol other than $r$ to represent $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$; perhaps call this quantity $\rho$.  In any case, you would be better off to integrate over $\theta$ and $\phi$ in spherical coordinates, expressing both $z$ and $\rho$ as functions of $\phi$.